# Why is the lettering on this Nikon 18-105mm engraved in black?

Tags: lens, nikon

I couldn't guess why it is in black colour. This feels so weird — usually Nikon lenses letters are engraved in gold or red, but this one
in black. Could anyone shed light on this?
(This is my friend's DSLR.)

[image]

Comment: With vague apologies for the cynicism: where did your friend buy this lens from, and was it much cheaper than official retailers?

Comment: https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/331/~/what-is-gray-market%3F (Maybe)

Answer (score 1):

This lens uses embossed lettering for the name plate, so it's probably not filled with black anything, it's just a sticker that's been ripped off of the lens. However, the VR marking also is in black, so I'm going to guess that someone impulsively ripped the badges off of this lens.